# Mockito, what am I doing wrong testing Post method in Controller?

Tags: java, spring, mockito

Here is my test

```
        @Test
    @WithMockUser(authorities = "ADMIN")
void shouldCreateRestaurant_whenPost() throws Exception {
        // when
        mockMvc.perform(
                post("/restaurant/admin/")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(this.objectMapper.writeValueAsString(RESTAURANT_CREATION_DOMINOS)));
        // then
        Mockito.verify(restaurantService, times(1)).create(RESTAURANT_CREATION_DOMINOS);
    }
```

It fails because it compares object with =. First object RestaurantCreationDTO@5980fa73, second RestaurantCreationDTO@15a8cebd.
But how can I make sure that restaurantService is called with a valid argument?

Comment: As part of your unit testing, you should be  verifying how many times a service is called. where in you unit test, you are comparing the DTOs?

Comment: Do you want to check if the service is called with the posted object in the request or checking if a `RestaurantCreationDTO` is used in the call to the Service is enough?

Comment: Hi, you can put your error logs in code fences to increase readbality. good luck:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

**First** - If it is enough to check if the object in the service call is indeed a `RestaurantCreationDTO`:

```
Mockito.verify(restaurantService, times(1)).create(any(RestaurantCreationDTO.class));
```

**Second** - If you really want to check the object content in the service call

In your Test class

```
@Captor
ArgumentCaptor<RestaurantCreationDTO> restaurantCreationDtoCaptor;
```

In your Test method

```
Mockito.verify(restaurantService, times(1)).create(restaurantCreationDtoCaptor.capture());
assertThat(restaurantCreationDtoCaptor.getValue()).isEqual(RESTAURANT_CREATION_DOMINOS)
```